# How to delete an uploaded youtube video from iPad but keep in the cloud?

Tags: ios, storage, youtube, ipados, icloud

I've uploaded few videos directly from my iPad to youtube, but now, I'm running out of space on the iPad and would like to reclaim some back by deleting the uploaded videos. However, I'm struggling to find an option to delete the videos just from the iPad while retaining them in the cloud.

Do I have to buy extra cloud storage to be able to do that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reclaiming hard drive space in iPad](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/20601/reclaiming-hard-drive-space-in-ipad)

Comment: Based on what do you assume they are still stored on the iPad?

Comment: @Rubén The answers there are >10 years old, not sure they still apply :-)

Comment: @nohillside Thanks for you reply. I haven't used an iPad in while so I can't tell :)

Comment: First clarifying question - to which cloud do you want to sync the files and free up?

Comment: @nohillside The "Documents & Data" under settings -> iPhone Storage -> youtube is more than 10GB

Comment: @bmike When I say cloud, I mean youtube (google cloud). I would like to keep it on youtube and delete from iPad. So, looking for a behavior similar to google photos app. After uploading photos/videos to google photos, I can delete them from the phone and reclaim the space. Hope I'm making sense here. Appreciate you all trying to resolve my issue. Thanks!